# How to find next highest MAX that does not equal value already listed

Tags: excel

Sorry for that bad title, wasn't sure the best way to title it was. Basically I have a list of prices that are either Standard Retail Price (SRP) or Promo Price. Problem here is that promo price can vary. How can I find the different prices? I have a MAX to find the SRP and a MIN to find the lowest promo price, and I need to find a price or prices in between the two.

I've tried index-match, match, maxifs, ifs, all to no avail. What seems to be missing?

[image: Here is what the layout will be like]

For example, if SRP is 6.29, and MIN promo is 4.99, but there was another promo listed at 5.59, I would expect the cell next to 4.99 to populate with 5.59, and I have tried a maxifs with <>

Comment: There may be many prices between maxSRP and minPromo.  Which of those "betweens" should be shown?  Please share with us some of the "list of prices"

Comment: Have you tried the large() function? Will get the largest or second or third largest value...

Comment: @SolarMike no I have not tried the large() function, that is something I was unfamiliar with. I will try that

Comment: @donPablo if there are multiple prices, then I want to list them in descending order. so anywhere between 6.29 and 4.99

Comment: If you have O365 with the `UNIQUE` function, you can use:  `=IFERROR(LARGE(UNIQUE(Prices),COLUMNS($A:A)),"")` and fill right.

Comment: solved? how does your min() & max() formula looks like?